# Python RuntimeError: error with Numpy installation

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm

Full error: RuntimeError: The current Numpy installation ('C:\Users\TomHu\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\**init**.py') fails to pass a sanity check due to a bug in the windows runtime. See this issue for more information: (a URL is here but stack overflow wouldnt allow it for some reason)
I have just started using pycharm after watching a youtube video about using simple machine learning to make a chatbot (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1lwddP0KUEg&t=284s you dont need to watch it as its unrelated to this but just if anyone cares) and the person in that used pycharm. I found it so much easier to use than the original/official python software. But I'm new to it so perhaps there is something to do with that. My Numpy module doesn't work and I'm not sure why. Importing it returns the above error. I have researched this for hours and I have found no solution. I tried changing the Numpy version to 1.19.3 as apparently 1.19.4 doesn't function on the Windows version I have. It may have something to do with PATH but I have tried to add it to PATH but to be honest, it went straight over my head. Please someone help me. Thanks in advance.

Edit: It had installed the 19.4 version through pycharm for some reason. Installing 19.3 through pycharm works perfectly. Thanks everyone!

Comment: What version of python you are using?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.9

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. You changed it to 1.19.3 and it gives you the same above error?

Comment: Yeah. I've changed the version and messed with PATH (idk what that is tbh) and it gives me the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install numpy via Pycharm settings

settings>>>project>>>python interpreter>>>+>>>numpy>>>install package

It`ll be better to create new enviroment and install it clear,
also you can install old and stable version via pycharm own terminal:

`pip install numpy==[stable version]`

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cd4z8.png)

!If you install package to PyCharm with pip... use pycharm`s terminal

[pycharm terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gape7.png)

Comment: It apparently had installed the 19.4 version despite me installing it time and time gain in 19.3 with command prompt. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Just reinstall NumPy. In the terminal, to uninstall NumPy

```
>>> pip uninstall numpy
>>> pip install numpy
```